# CMAKE How to set the working directory of an executable when generating for an IDE

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, cmake

For a project I build with Cmake I need to set the working directory of the final executable when generating for an IDE. Currently I am trying to do this for Xcode but I welcome anybody who know how to do the same for Visual Studio.

I have this hierarchy:

```
CMakeLists.txt
 |
 |- lib
    |- CMakeLists.txt
    -- ...
 |- exec (use the lib created in the lib folder)
    |-CMakeLists.txt
    ...
```

The executable is created in `exec` and uses the library compiled in `lib`.

For now I am using Xcode as the generator for Cmake. I need a way to give Xcode a working directory that is not the default one when executing the executable created at `exec`. To achieve that, I tried to set the property [`CMAKE_XCODE_SCHEME_WORKING_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_XCODE_SCHEME_WORKING_DIRECTORY.html) to the path I need but it doesn't work. No matter in which `CMakeLists.txt` file I set the property, the working directory I specified is never taken into account.

I tried to set the property at the top of the topmost CMakeLists, or before the `add_executable` of the CMakeLists inside the `exec` folder but it doesn't change anything, the Working directory is not the one I specified. When I go to the settings of the scheme, the working directory is still the default one.

I tried this:

Topmost `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(...)
set(CMAKE_XCODE_SCHEME_WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/exec/test)

#...

add_subdirectory(exec)
add_subdirectory(lib)
```

`CMakeLists.txt` inside exec:

```
project(...)

set(CMAKE_XCODE_SCHEME_WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/test)

#...

add_executable(...)

#...
```

My question is : In the case of Xcode : Why setting `CMAKE_XCODE_SCHEME_WORKING_DIRECTORY` doesn't do anything ? When reading the doc, I thought it solved exactly my problem. And if somebody knows how to do the same thing for Visual Studio I'm interested